# OpenCV SVM on IOS versus Computer

Tags: ios, opencv

I am developing an app that recognizes certain objects based on pictures obtained from the camera.

I am using as features: SIFT + RGB histogram.

I've ran a SVM on my computer (OSX) on 200+ images and saved a XML with both the SVM model and BOVW descriptors.
When I test my model on the computer for resubstitution error, I get a perfect score.

When I load these files on iOS, my classifier won't get a single image correctly classified. I've tested with the same pictures used for training too, but still got a 0% accuracy.

[EDIT] Both opencv versions are 3.0
Ideas?

Comment: Same OpenCV version on both computers?

Comment: @Miki, yes! both 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I haven't found the solution, but I'd suggest to start by ensuring the colorspace of your ios cv::Mat matches up to the one on the computer. Remember that by default openCV uses BGR. I've added some code to help with checking.

```
cv::Vec4b rgbPixel = m.at<cv::Vec4b>(100,100);
CGImageRef cgimage = image.CGImage;
size_t bpr = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgimage);
size_t bpp = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(cgimage);
size_t bpc = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgimage);
size_t bytes_per_pixel = bpp / bpc;

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgimage);
NSData* data = (id)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));
const uint8_t* bytes = (const uint8_t *) [data bytes];
const uint8_t *pixel =  &bytes[100 * bpr + 100 * bytes_per_pixel];
NSLog(@"bgr pixel %d %d %d %d rows %d cols %d",rgbPixel[0],rgbPixel[1], rgbPixel[2], rgbPixel[3], m.rows, m.cols);
NSLog(@"rgb bpr %lu bpp %lubpc %lu Bpp %lu rows %f cols %f", bpr, bpp, bpc, bytes_per_pixel, rows,cols);
NSLog(@"rgb piexel %d %d %d %d", pixel[0],pixel[1],pixel[2], pixel[3]);
```